# Div not stretching depending on content generated by php

Tags: php, html

I am using wordpress to generate a ul list, and I'd like the container div (that has background-texture) to stretch vertically, depending on how many li items user generates in Wordpress.

Code:

```
.black-bg-section   {
background-color:#CCC;
}

#departments    {
width:500px;
}
```

---

```
<div class="black-bg-section" id="departments">
<?php the_block('school-departments')?>
</div>
```

I guess it has to do something with the content to be generated by php. If I copy paste this into a new document and make an  list inside that div, it works flawlessly.

Any help how to tackle this will be much appreciated.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the content being generated by php. Php runs server side then sends the html to the browser. The browser then renders the html.

Comment: Use a HTML debug tool in Chrome or Firefox to check the real height of the `ul`

Comment: Once it displays in browser look at the HTML source code, most likely you have an element that is `float`ing and there is no div to `clear`

Comment: can you post the function so we can see the loop, i bet that is where the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a div or some other element that is being generated that has the css property of: `float: left;` or `float: right;`. If there is one simply add this:

```
<div class="black-bg-section" id="departments">
    <?php the_block('school-departments')?>
    <div style='clear: left;'></div> <!-- or clear: right if that is what the float is -->
</div>
```